# Read objects from file c++

Tags: c++, file

I want to read 3 objects from file. For example, in main I wrote:

```
ifstream fis;
Person pp;
fis >> pp;
Person cc;
fis >> cc;
Person dd;
fis >> dd;
```

The problem is that for every Person, it reads me 3 objects. I need to create an array of objects?

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream&fis, Person &p){

    fis.open("fis.txt", ios::in);
    while (!fis.eof())
    {
        char temp[100];
        char* name;
        fis >> temp;
        name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, temp);
        int age;
        fis >> age;


        Person p(name, age);
        cout << p;
    }

    fis.close();
    return fis;
}
```

Comment: " it reads me 3 objects" please add example that will show what you are thinking about

Comment: In file I have : Maria 12 John 13 Smith 12. I want to read for person pp just   Maria 12. But for Person pp, it reads me all the names:Maria 12 John 13 Smith 12

Comment: So remove `while (!fis.eof())`

Comment: I try to remove while. Then for every object reads just Maria 12

Comment: ifstream fis;
Persoana pp;
Persoana cc;
Persoana dd;
fis >> pp>>cc>>dd;

Comment: what about std::strings instead  of char[]?

Comment: Ew... why the `new`, arrays, pointers?!

Comment: i think your problem might be solved by now, it'd still be a good idea to edit your question and add the output given by your code to enable people with a similar problem to recognize what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you use `operator>>` you should prepare stream that you want to read from.

```
ifstream fis;
fis.open("fis.txt", ios::in);
Person pp;
fis >> pp;
Person cc;
fis >> cc;
Person dd;
fis >> dd;
fis.close();
```

Your code should look like this.

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream&fis, Person &p) {
    char temp[100];
    char* name;
    fis >> temp;
    name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(name, temp);
    int age;
    fis >> age;
    Person p(name, age);
    cout << p;
    return fis;
}
```

Consider adding additional checking if stream is not empty and using `string`s instead of `char*`

Answer (score 5):

**Problem:**

You're opening and closing the input stream inside of your `operator>>`. So everytime it is executed it opens your file at the beginning, then reads to the end and closes the file again. At the next call it starts all over again.

**Explaination:**

The used input stream keeps track of it's current reading position. If you reinitialize the stream in every call, you reset the position in the file thus starting at the beginning again. If you're interested you can also check the position with [std::ifstream::tellg()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/).

**Possible solution:**

Prepare the input stream outside of `operator>>`, then just read one dataset per call. After all reading is done close the file on the outside.

**Example:**

Calling code:

```
#include<fstream>

// ... other code

std::ifstream fis;
Person pp, cc, dd;

fis.open("fis.txt", std::ios::in); // prepare input stream

fis >> pp;
fis >> cc;
fis >> dd;

fis.close(); // after reading is done: close input stream
```

`operator>>` code:

```
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& fis, Person &p)
{
    // only read if everything's allright (e.g. eof not reached)
    if (fis.good())
    {
        // read to p ...
    }

    /*
     * return input stream (whith it's position pointer
     * right after the data just read, so you can start
     * from there at your next call)
     */
    return fis;
}
```

Comment: as this is your first question: if my answer (or the answer of another user) solved your problem you are able to 'accept' it. You maybe want to take some time to also consider other proposed approaches before doing so.